# Webpack: split some entries to chunks, but others - don't

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, chunks, webpacker

Is it possible to have one webpack dev server that's configured with multiple entry points (there are multiple pages on the site), each with a different configuration?

Specifically, I want one entry (the page's JS code) to be split into chunks, but another entry (JS localization bundle with translated messages) not to be chunked.

One possible complication, which you may ignore if you wish, is that I'm using Ruby-on-Rails webpacker, which automagically creates some of the webpack configuration for me.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use a function for `optimization.splitChunks.chunks` to exclude your localization bundle by name as shown in the example in the Webpack docs: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#splitchunkschunks

In Webpacker land, it might look like the following:

```js
environment.splitChunks((config) => Object.assign({}, config, { 
  optimization: { 
    splitChunks: {
      chunks(chunk) {
        // exclude `my-excluded-chunk`
        return chunk.name !== 'my-excluded-chunk';
      } 
    }
  }
}))
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. To test, I set `optimization.runtimeChunk` to `multiple` and added the `chunks` function. It still generated a runtime JS file for both main file and translation file.

Comment: @Barak: you can set it to `single` if you just want one runtime `.js` file.